# How to save Application data

Tags: qt, user-interface

Generally, how to save application data?

In a binary file,  or a database? In other words, which structure can I use?

If there is a database table, how can I select data from it?

Comment: What do you mean by application data?  Do you have a specific example of the data you want to save?

Comment: User data: If there is More than one chip , a table holds the voltage data of each chip pin. Initial data: the layout of the application..

Comment: @Tu_JianWu, to make your application maintainable on the long term, it seems that you need a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple applications settings, use `QSettings` - it provides persistent platform-independent application settings.

For more complex data, you might want to have a look at `QSqlDatabase`, several databases are supported, including SQLite. To select data or, more generally, to make an SQL query, have a look at `QSqlQuery`.

Comment: yeah! Thank you for helping me..I am a beginner.. this question confused me long time..when i use some software, i don't know the data how to save..Recently, when i study Qt, and do some project, i dont't know which way i can use, In class, teacher teach us how to open a binary file , but didn't said other, so i ask this question. thanks again..

Comment: more, If i want to save data like doc? how can i do ? thank you.

Comment: If you want save data to a file, you serialize your data to some format (say, XML, using QXmlStreamWriter) and save it to a file (QFile).

Comment: @tu_jianwu, I'd follow Frank's advice. Doc files are not portable so avoid that if possible. Look for a format like ODT, which are open, and essentially just zipped XML files. They can also be opened with any recent version of MS Office.

Comment: Laurent: Ever wrote an ODT reader? Sounds like overkill for most app-specific file formats...

Comment: Ah if it's an app-specific format, then indeed he doesn't need to save to ODT. He mentioned doc earlier, that's why I assumed he needed some file format that can be read by other applications.

Comment: app-specific file format ? can you give more information about it ?  Curious.. Thank you two..